# jQuery always prevents the action of the first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magnific-popup

I have several "Purchase Now" buttons of different articles. When the button has the class "sold-out" it shouldn't do anything otherwise it should open a jQuery Magnific Popup. So far that works. My problem is, that when I click for the first time I visit the homepage the purchaseable "Purchase Now" button, it isn't doing anything. When I click for the second time on it, it opens the jQuery window. But why it doesn't work for the first time already ??

**My HTML:**

```
<a href="payment_options.php" class="btn-1 ajax-popup" data-region="EUW" data-packageid="1" style="display: inline-block;">Purchase Now</a>
```

**My JQuery:**

```
$('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
  type:'inline',
  midClick: true,
  mainClass: 'mfp-fade'
});



$('.ajax-popup').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if($(this).hasClass("sold-out")) {
        return false;
    }
    var region = $(this).data('region');
    var quantity = $(this).data('quantity');
    if(typeof quantity == 'undefined') quantity = $(this).parent().find('select').val();
    var packageid = $(this).data('packageid');

    $(this).magnificPopup({
      type: 'ajax',
      ajax: {
          settings: {
              data : {
                  region : region,
                  quantity : quantity,
                  packageid : packageid,
              }
          }
      },
      closeOnContentClick: false,
      closeOnBgClick: false
   });

});
```

Comment: You are setting `magnificPopup` on elements only once you have clicked on it, so this open only after second click

Comment: Haven't I declared this with the first part of my jQuery ? What should I do to fix this ?? When I use the mousedown event handler instead of click eventhandler it works. But I need the click handler

Comment: Doesn't it work `$('.ajax-popup').each(function(){$(this).magnificPopup(...);});` outside of click handler?

Comment: I don't get your idea A.Wolff ? What should I state inside `magnificPopup(...)` ?

Comment: Instead of click handler, use an each loop to set plugin with respective data

Comment: Using each as event handler doesn't open the popup anymore, but it redirects to the checkout.php page which is stated in the HTML. I guess because the preventDefault() isn't working anymore.

Comment: But you still have to prevent default behaviour of click... Use `each` loop to only set plugin, i was thinking it was obvious

Comment: Ok when I use the each event handler to initialize the magnific popup first it says "Content Not found" for the first click, and it opens the correct popup at the second click. This is how I've did this: http://pastebin.com/kVUk1md7 . What I've tried before this comment was this: http://pastebin.com/RHpy8dHa

Comment: Could you post a jsFiddle instead, so it can be checked?  BUT, you are still recalling plugin initialization in click, this isn't what i was telling. BTW, you need to pass specific data in the each loop.  `$('.ajax-popup').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();}).each(function(){if($(this).hasClass("sold-out")) {...//all code here});`

Comment: Here is the fiddle. The "Content couldn't loaded" only appears at the second click. Maybe you can provide me a working solution with this. Thanks for your help! http://jsfiddle.net/fyLgp1yx/

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you are declaring the popup definition within the click function. Can you try declaring the function outside the click function?

Comment: @kentor Ya because mousedown is fired before click event which is used to open the popup. But then you are reinitializing plugin on each mousedown

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't open on first click cause this is the time you BIND it to the element.

Hovewer, we see in documentation that we can instantly open MagnificPopup.

```
// Open popup immediately. If popup is already opened - it'll just overwite the content (but old options will be kept).
// - first parameter: options object
// - second parameter (optional): index of item to open
$.magnificPopup.open({
  items: {
    src: 'someimage.jpg'
  },
  type: 'image'

  // You may add options here, they're exactly the same as for $.fn.magnificPopup call
  // Note that some settings that rely on click event (like disableOn or midClick) will not work here
}, 0);
```

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#options

Comment: I've added the .open to my magnificPopup line like this `$(this).magnificPopup.open({` . Hasn't changed anything.

Comment: I tried creating page with your code and adding open() method, and can say that it fixed the issue.
http://jsbin.com/yepowicaza/1/edit?html,js
(you can see my test code there, I only changed ajax to inline popup to simplify testing)

Comment: `$.magnificPopup.open({` <- this line is throwing an error for me. Cannot read property "parsed" of undefined.

Comment: I just changed type to ajax and run with it, it also shows ok. I think that your issue is that you misplaced pieces of code. Something is just not loaded when it's executing first time(and seems it's Popup). F.e., try putting all code in the end of the file. I bet 95% that the issue is somewhere here.

Comment: Why do you load Popup twice, minified and full version? That may be cause of errors. And for browser anyway they are the same.

Comment: <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

Comment: Ok I outlined the min version, but its still the same error. But I also wonder about that syntax where the error occurs, never seen before ?

Comment: It says that item is undefined and even clearly shows the line `  if(!item.parsed) {
   item = mfp.parseEl( mfp.index );
  }` now it's for you to understand why is it undefined here) seems you missed some Popup settings